# jQuery .not not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with jQuery .not() not working.

I've got a pricing table with 3 products, when you mouse over each of the products a description appears and then disappears on mouse out so far everything works fine.

The problem however is that on page load one of the three products (each held in an `<aside>`) will have a `.selected` class applied to it and I need the mouseenter/leave function to not run on this `<aside>`.

The only caveat is that clicking any of the `<button>'s` in each `<aside>` will remove the `.selected` class from it's current `<aside>` and apply to the `<button>'s <aside>` parent (I've not included the JQ for this as it's just a dead simple `.addClass`).

Code example of what I currently have is below, thanks in advanced.

**jQuery**

```
$(".pricing3 aside").not('.selected').mouseenter(function() {
$(".desc", this).stop().slideDown('slow');
})
.mouseleave(function() {
$(".desc", this).stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pricing3">
  <aside>
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    <h3>1 Hour Pass</h3>
    <p class="desc">Description</p>
    <p class="pricing">£XX</p>
    <button type="submit">BUY NOW</button>
  </aside>
  <aside class="selected">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    <h3>8 Hour Pass</h3>
    <p class="desc">Description</p>
    <p class="pricing">£XX</p>
    <button type="submit">BUY NOW</button>
  </aside>
  <aside>
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    <h3>24-7-365 Access</h3>
    <p class="desc">Description</p>
    <p class="pricing">£XX</p>
    <button type="submit">BUY NOW</button>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Several of the solutions seem to correctly identify the issue that you need to use event delegation.  But I think you might have another issue lurking.  If `mouseleave` collapses the description, but not of _selected_ items, and the button is inside that item, then clicking the button will leave the description expanded.  I may have your intent wrong, but see **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/8dbB4/)** for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as the target element selection is based on a dynamic state

```
$(".pricing3").on('mouseenter', 'aside:not(.selected)', function () {
    $(".desc", this).stop().slideDown('slow');
}).on('mouseleave', 'aside:not(.selected)', function () {
    $(".desc", this).stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

It can be written slightly differently as

```
$(".pricing3").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(".desc", this).stop().slideDown('slow');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(".desc", this).stop().slideUp('slow');
    }
}, 'aside:not(.selected)')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the class is shifting you'd be better off checking for the class inside the event handler

```
$(".pricing3 aside").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(".desc", this).stop().slideToggle('slow');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that you want the `.selected` to be removed, and then the `mouseenter()` to run on it as if it hadn't had the `.selected` on it in the first place?

If this is the case, you should attach your event handler higher up the DOM tree, and use `on()` to filter down to the `<aside>`s  This way you can flip/flop the class all you want, and the event handler will work as expected.  As it's coded, you are only applying the filter at page load, so the state change of the class has no effect.